# How to search for flights using the Amadeus API and Python, by considering the originRadius and destinationRadius parameters?

Tags: python, amadeus

I am trying to get Amadeus API flight data by considering the originRadius and destinationRadius parameters. Can someone help me with that? How can I search for flights by considering these two parameters?

Currently, I have implemented following code:

```
def check_flights(
    self, 
    originLocationCode, 
    destinationLocationCode, 
    departureDate, 
    returnDate, 
    adults, 
    currencyCode
):
    ''' Return a list of FlightData objects based on the API search results. '''
    
    amadeus = Client(client_id=API_KEY, client_secret=API_SECRET)
    
    try:
        response = amadeus.get(
            API_URL, 
            originLocationCode=originLocationCode, 
            destinationLocationCode=destinationLocationCode, 
            departureDate=departureDate, 
            returnDate=returnDate, 
            adults=adults, 
            currencyCode=currencyCode
        )
        data = response.data

        self.save_data_to_file(data=response.body)

    except ResponseError as error:
        # TO DO: If error occurs, render error in available_flights
        return error
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  This is not your personal code writing service.  If you have a specific question, post it with code you have written.

Comment: Hi possum. Thank you for your advice. I edited the initial post by adding the code.

Answer (score 0):

For that you will have to use the `POST` method of the Flight Offers Search API. I leave an example below that takes into consideration the `originRadius`. This parameter includes other possible locations around the point, located less than this distance in kilometers away with a max of 300km and it can not be combined with `dateWindow` or `timeWindow`.

`POST https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers`

```
{
    "originDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "originLocationCode": "MAD",
            "destinationLocationCode": "ATH",
            "originRadius": "299",
            "departureDateTimeRange": {
                "date": "2023-03-03"
            }
        }
    ],
    "travelers": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "travelerType": "ADULT"
        }
    ],
    "sources": [
        "GDS"
    ]
}
```

The logic is the same for the `destinationRadius`.

For more details check the Amadeus for Developers [API reference](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference).